# Why the function does not return the new value [Python]

Tags: python

The practice question is to return cube of the input value if the value is divisible by 3. Elsewise return false.

The code structure is compilable but it does not return the cube value. Instead it returns the original input value.

```
a=raw_input("Enter a number")
number=int(a)

def cube(number):

    number=number**3
    print" The answer is %s" % number
    return number

def by_three(number):
    if number%3==0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False

print" The answer is %s" % number
```

Comment: You're never calling either of your functions.

Comment: Please post a compilable version of your code. This is riddled with indentation headaches.

Comment: Hi, please kindly show appreciation by clicking the green arrow to pick an answer you deem most useful. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace. Indent your `if` statement.

```
def by_three(number):
    if number%3==0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```

(edit: from Ryan's comment)

To fix the runtime error... you never call the functions you define. This should do ya:

```
print "The answer is %s" % by_three(number)
```

Alternatively...

```
a=raw_input("Enter a number")
number=int(a)

if number%3==0:
    number = number**3
else:
    number = False

print "The answer is %s" % number
```

Comment: If this were the problem, it would be a syntax error, not a runtime bug.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by _"Dynamic whitespace"_? I've never heard this term before.

Comment: dynamic whitespace: Python uses indentation, rather than braces, to delineate blocks of code

Comment: You just invented that term, didn't you?

Comment: @ddg I'm still not sure I understand. Why the "dynamic" part? Python's whitespace rules don't change during run-time, so "dynamic" seems out of place. "Indentation rules" or "Indention matters" seem like better way's to describe Python's syntax.

Comment: Uh, it turns out I made it up from misreading https://xkcd.com/353/ a couple years ago. This is pretty embarrassing tbh.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function `by_three` in the code. Why you did not get the result you wanted is because the function was declared, but never called. The correct code is provided below:

```
a=raw_input("Enter a number ")
number=int(a)

def cube(number):   
    number=number**3
    #print" The answer is %s" % number
    return number

def by_three(number):
    if number%3==0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False

# call the function `by_three` and pass number as a parameter
print" The answer is %s" % by_three(number)
```